# Decoding Variables for JavaScript Pro And those who love challenges

Tags: javascript

Recently I was updating some features on a site I'm working on locally until I launch it soon but I found a site that uses the code below to display some features that I want to add in my site template but I'm 10% Javascript I don't understand the code at all so is it possible to decode The code so that I can learn from it?

```js
const jo = {};
! function JetThemeScript() {
    var U = window,
        aZ = document,
        a = setTimeout,
        cK = clearTimeout,
        cN = Date,
        cA = Math,
        w = parseInt,
        cn = encodeURIComponent,
        an = RegExp,
        cy = XMLHttpRequest,
        bG = alert,
        b1 = localStorage,
        aH = JSON,
        bh = Image,
        bl = setInterval,
        dr = clearInterval,
        bw = "innerHTML",
        be = "outerHTML",
        ck = "tagName",
        C = "getElementById",
        s = "getElementsByClassName",
        bR = "querySelector",
        dd = "querySelectorAll",
        bN = "documentElement",
        cV = "childNodes",
        bL = "parentNode",
        bO = "cloneNode",
        cg = "createElement",
        H = "className",
        L = "replace",
        cx = "indexOf",
        q = "lastIndexOf",
        bk = "EventListener",
        cO = "add",
        aV = "remove",
        cW = "id",
        bM = "key",
        aU = "type",
        ap = "parse",
        df = "length",
        ag = "call",
        b8 = "slice",
        I = "reset",
        aJ = "scroller",
        aC = "push",
        cF = "Time",
        ak = "Date",
        bq = "Month",
        bo = "FullYear",
        aB = "clientX",
        aA = "clientY",
        k = "pageX",
        j = "pageY",
        aW = "scrollLeft",
        cl = "scrollTop",
        am = "onreadystatechange",
        cT = "readyState",
        bg = "Attribute",
        bD = "set",
        bY = "get",
        bf = "has",
        N = "checked",
        aD = "focus",
        cD = "height",
        cP = "offsetWidth",
        cY = "offsetHeight",
        aI = "toFixed",
        aO = "pageYOffset",
        dg = "appendChild",
        bX = "firstChild",
        cX = "insert",
        cm = "Before",
        aM = "value",
        aa = "safe",
        aR = "match",
        ah = "href",
        bB = "src",
        ad = "onload",
        aw = "onerror",
        T = "target",
        ct = "closest",
        bx = "location",
        bC = "reload",
        bs = "split",
        bp = "trim",
        cz = "open",
        bz = "send",
        bE = "random",
        dq = "status",
        bJ = "toString",
        a8 = "parentElement",
        ay = "activeElement",
        cL = "preventDefault",
        bt = "substr",
        c8 = "setRequestHeader",
        aN = "responseText",
        cZ = "response",
        br = "body",
        a3 = "title",
        at = "test",
        aL = "container",
        a5 = "ceil",
        au = "floor",
        bP = "round",
        aq = "min",
        db = "map",
        c0 = "cookie",
        ae = "contains",
        by = "toUTCString",
        cp = "textContent",
        aG = "elementFromPoint",
        a2 = "Item",
        cc = "nextSibling",
        dn = "load",
        bI = "true",
        D = "false",
        a9 = "valid",
        cu = "scroll",
        O = "click",
        b3 = "blur",
        cj = "mousemove",
        u = "mouseup",
        aj = "touchstart",
        a7 = "mousedown",
        bd = "change",
        m = "complete",
        dp = "undefined",
        bK = "function",
        bT = "Content-Type",
        Y = "text/html",
        ba = "overlays",
        f = "pagination",
        da = "loadCustomPosts",
        l = "custom_posts",
        X = "config",
        dm = "adsbygoogle",
        cv = "enable_page_level_ads",
        b6 = "analytics",
        a6 = "firebase",
        v = "8.4.2",
        dj = typeof isPreview !== dp ? isPreview : false,
        aP = typeof siteUrl !== dp ? siteUrl : "",
        aX = typeof currentUrl !== dp ? currentUrl : "",
        y = typeof blogId !== dp ? blogId : "",
        c2 = typeof blogTitle !== dp ? blogTitle : "",
        cH = typeof pageTitle !== dp ? pageTitle : "Page",
        b = typeof firebaseUrl !== dp ? firebaseUrl : "",
        B = typeof analyticId !== dp ? analyticId : false,
        a1 = typeof caPubAdsense !== dp ? caPubAdsense : false,
        ch = typeof innerAdsDelimiter !== dp ? innerAdsDelimiter : "p,br,div",
        cf = typeof ignoreAdsDelimiter !== dp ? ignoreAdsDelimiter : "pre,ul,ol,table,blockquote",
        bH = typeof autoTOC !== dp ? autoTOC : false,
        av = typeof toc_temp === bK ? toc_temp : false,
        bn = typeof generate_url_temp === bK ? generate_url_temp : false,
        r = typeof positionTOC !== dp ? positionTOC : false,
        bu = typeof jtCallback === bK ? jtCallback : false,
        z = "jet",
        cR = "https://",
        aF = "-rw",
        a0 = "5.0.0-beta2",
        cC = "theme",
        bQ = "bootstrap",
        c7 = typeof licenseKey !== dp ? licenseKey : "",
        R = typeof bootstrapJs !== dp ? bootstrapJs : false,
        a4 = typeof bsCallback === bK ? bsCallback : false,
        bW = typeof safeAds !== dp ? safeAds : false,
        cb = typeof limitAdsClick !== dp ? limitAdsClick : 3,
        bj = typeof timeAdsClick !== dp ? timeAdsClick : 10,
        bi = typeof blockAdsClick !== dp ? blockAdsClick : 6,
        af = "source",
        cM = "app",
        W = "please",
        bF = "license",
        bc = "Newspaper";

    function S(i, h) {
        return -1 < (" " + i[H] + " ")[cx](" " + h + " ")
    }

    function Q(i, h) {
        if (!S(i, h)) {
            var n = i[H];
            "" != n && (h = " " + h), i[H] = n + h
        }
    }

    function bV(i, h) {
        i[H] = i[H][L](new an("(?:^|\\s)" + h + "(?!\\S)"), "")[bp]()
    }

    function bS(i, h) {
        S(i, h) ? bV(i, h) : Q(i, h)
    }

    function aT(i, h) {
        Q(i, "d-block"), a(function () {
            Q(i, h)
        }, 100)
    }

    function cJ(i, h, n) {
        bV(i, h), a(function () {
            bV(i, "d-block")
        }, n ? n : 300)
    }

    function G(i, h) {
        for (var n = 0; n < i[df]; n++) {
            if (i[n] === h) {
                return !0
            }
        }
        return !1
    }

    function aQ() {
        return (cA[bE]() + 1)[bJ](36)[bt](7)
    }

    function c3(i, h) {
        return i = new an("[?&]" + i + "=([^&#=]*)"), !!i[at](h) && h[aR](i)[1]
    }

    function ab(dy, dx, dw, dv) {
        dy = w(dy), dx = w(dx), dw = w(dw), dv = w(dv);
        var dt, x, t = cA[a5](dy / dw);
        (1 > dx ? dx = 1 : dx > t && (dx = t), t <= dv) ? (dt = 1, x = t) : (dy = cA[au](dv / 2), dw = cA[a5](dv / 2) - 1, dx <= dy ? (dt = 1, x = dv) : dx + dw >= t ? (dt = t - dv + 1, x = t) : (dt = dx - dy, x = dx + dw));
        for (var o = (dx - 1) * dw, ds = cA[aq](o + dw - 1, dy - 1), du = [], n = 0; n < x + 1 - dt; n++) {
            du[aC](n)
        }
        return du = du[db](function (h) {
            return dt + h
        }), {
            totalItems: dy,
            currentPage: dx,
            pageSize: dw,
            totalPages: t,
            startPage: dt,
            endPage: x,
            startIndex: o,
            endIndex: ds,
            pages: du
        }
    }! function (i) {
        var h = new bh;
        h[ad] = h[aw] = function () {
            i(2 == h[cD])
        }, h[bB] = "data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjoAAABXRUJQVlA4IC4AAACyAgCdASoCAAIALmk0mk0iIiIiIgBoSygABc6WWgAA/veff/0PP8bA//LwYAAA"
    }(function (h) {
        h || (aF = "")
    });

    function c9(i) {
        for (var h = i.slice(), t = h[df] - 1; 0 < t; t--) {
            var o = cA[au](cA[bE]() * (t + 1)),
                n = h[t];
            h[t] = h[o], h[o] = n
        }
        return h
    }

    function dl(o, n, i, dt) {
        var x = new cN,
            ds = "minutes" == dt ? 1000 * (60 * i) : "hours" == dt ? 1000 * (60 * (60 * i)) : 1000 * (60 * (60 * (24 * i)));
        x[bD + cF](x[bY + cF]() + ds);
        var t = "expires=" + x[by]();
        aZ[c0] = o + "=" + n + "; " + t + "; path=/"
    }

    function p(i) {
        var h = aZ[c0][aR](new an("(^| )" + i + "=([^;]+)"));
        if (h) {
            return h[2]
        }
    }

    function az(h) {
        try {
            return aH[ap](h)
        } catch (h) {
            return !1
        }
    }
    var dc = aZ[C]("header"),
        cs = aZ[C]("search-toggle"),
        ac = aZ[C]("search-header"),
        g = aZ[C]("navbar-toggle"),
        bm = aZ[C]("navbar"),
        aE = aZ[C]("back-to-top"),
        di = aZ[C]("dark-toggler"),
        bb = aZ[bR]("html"),
        cr = aZ[C]("comment-button"),
        al = aZ[C]("threaded-comment-form"),
        c6 = aZ[C]("comment-editor"),
        c4 = aZ[C]("comment-editor-src"),
        V = aZ[C]("comment-script"),
        bU = aZ[dd](".comment-reply"),
        P = aZ[dd](".entry-text noscript"),
        aK = aZ[C]("ads-post"),
        cU = aZ[C]("post-body"),
        aS = aZ[bR](".related-posts"),
        aY = aZ[bR](".related-inline"),
        ao = c3("page", aX),
        ai = aZ[dd](".generate-url"),
        c1 = aP[bt](0, aP[df] - 1)[L](/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, ""),
        ca = c7[bp](),
        cw = p("j" + bM),
        dh = p("j" + a9),
        c5 = p("j" + aa) ? w(p("j" + aa)) : 0,
        d = cR + af + "." + z + cC + ".com/" + cM + "?" + bB + "=" + ca,
        M = function (n) {
            if ("IMG" == n[ck]) {
                var i = n[bY + bg]("data-src");
                if (0 < i[cx]("bp.blogspot")) {
                    var du = n[cP][aI](0),
                        dt = n[a8][cP][aI](0),
                        ds = n[a8][a8][cP][aI](0),
                        x = n[cY][aI](0),
                        t = i[bs]("/"),
                        o = "";
                    S(n[a8], "ratio") ? o = "w" + du + aF + "-h" + x + "-c" : (o = 10 > du ? 10 > dt ? ds : dt : du, o = "s" + o + aF), i = i[L](t[t[df] - 2], o), n[bD + bg]("data-src", i)
                } else {
                    i[aR](/(img.youtube|i.ytimg)/) && (i = i[bt](0, i[q]("/")) + "/mqdefault.jpg", n[bD + bg]("data-src", i))
                }
            }
        },
        dk = function (dw) {
            var dv = dw[bY + bg]("data-pagination");
            if (dv != D) {
                function dv(dy, dx, dB) {
                    var dA = aZ[cg]("li"),
                        dz = aZ[cg]("span");
                    return Q(dz, "btn btn-sm rounded-pill jt-icon-center"), dz[bw] = dB ? dB : dy, dz[bD + bg]("data-page", dy), dy == dx ? Q(dz, "jt-btn-primary") : (Q(dz, "jt-btn-light hover-btn-primary"), dz[cO + bk](O, function (dC) {
                        if (dC[cL](), i = dz[bY + bg]("data-page"), 1 == i) {
                            var h = dt ? aP + "search" + x + "?max-results=" + du + "&page=" + i : aP;
                            U[bx][ah] = h
                        } else {
                            var dD = (i - 1) * du;
                            Defer.js(aP + "feeds/posts/summary/" + ds + "?start-index=" + dD + "&alt=json&callback=jo." + f + "_date&max-results=1")
                        }
                    })), dA[dg](dz), dA
                }
                var du = dw[bY + bg]("data-posts"),
                    dt = dw[bY + bg]("data-label");
                dt = cn(dt);
                var ds = dt ? "-/" + dt + "/" : "",
                    x = dt ? "/label/" + dt : "";
                Defer.js(aP + "feeds/posts/summary/" + ds + "?alt=json&callback=jo." + f + "_" + bM + "&max-results=1");
                var t = c3("max-results", aX),
                    o = c3("page", aX),
                    n = t ? t : du,
                    i = o ? o : 1;
                jo[f + "_" + bM] = function (dG) {
                    var dF = dG.feed,
                        dE = w(dF.openSearch$totalResults.$t);
                    if (dE > du) {
                        var dG = ab(dE, i, n, 5),
                            dD = aZ[cg]("ul"),
                            dC = 1,
                            dB = dG.totalPages;
                        if (dG.currentPage != dC) {
                            var dA = dv(dG.currentPage - 1, "", '<svg aria-hidden="true" class="jt-icon"><use xlink:href="#i-arrow-l"/></svg>');
                            dD[dg](dA)
                        }
                        if (!G(dG.pages, dC)) {
                            var dz = dv(dC, dG.currentPage, dC + " . .");
                            dD[dg](dz)
                        }
                        for (var dz, dy = 0; dy < dG.pages[df]; dy++) {
                            dz = dv(dG.pages[dy], dG.currentPage), dD[dg](dz)
                        }
                        if (!G(dG.pages, dB)) {
                            var dz = dv(dB, dG.currentPage, ". . " + dB);
                            dD[dg](dz)
                        }
                        if (dG.currentPage != dB) {
                            var dx = dv(dG.currentPage + 1, "", '<svg aria-hidden="true" class="jt-icon"><use xlink:href="#i-arrow-r"/></svg>');
                            dD[dg](dx)
                        }
                        dw[bw] = "", Q(dD, "pagination mb-0"), dw[dg](dD), bV(dw, "visually-hidden")
                    }
                }, jo[f + "_date"] = function (dx) {
                    var h = dx.feed.entry[0],
                        dz = h.published.$t[bt](0, 19) + h.published.$t[bt](23, 29);
                    dz = dz[L]("+", "%2B");
                    var dy = aP + "search" + x + "?updated-max=" + dz + "&max-results=" + n + "&page=" + i;
                    U[bx][ah] = dy
                }
            } else {
                bV(dw, "visually-hidden")
            }
        };
    jo[da] = function (dC) {
        var dB = aQ(),
            dA = dC[bY + bg]("data-label"),
            dz = dC[bY + bg]("data-title"),
            dy = dC[bY + bg]("data-items"),
            dx = dC[bY + bg]("data-shuffle"),
            dw = dC[bY + bg]("data-no-item"),
            dv = dC[bY + bg]("data-func"),
            du = dC[bY + bg]("data-callback"),
            dt = dw ? w(dy) + 1 : dy,
            ds = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            x = dA ? dA : dC[bw],
            t = x[bs](","),
            i = "";
        i = 1 < t[df] ? x ? "-/" + cn(t[cA[au](cA[bE]() * t[df])]) + "/?" : "?" : x && x != D ? "-/" + cn(x[bp]()) + "/?" : "?", Defer.js(aP + "feeds/posts/summary/" + i + "alt=json&callback=jo." + l + "_" + bM + "_" + dB + "&max-results=" + dt), jo[l + "_" + bM + "_" + dB] = function (dK) {
            var dJ = w(dK.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t),
                dI = dK.feed.category;
            if (0 < dJ) {
                for (var dH = {
                        title: dz,
                        posts: [],
                        categories: dI
                    }, dF = dK.feed.entry, dD = 0, h = 0; h < dF[df]; ++h) {
                    var dS = dF[h],
                        dR = dS.link[dS.link[df] - 1][ah];
                    if (dD == dy) {
                        break
                    }
                    if (dR != dw) {
                        dD++;
                        var dQ = {
                                grup_id: dB,
                                url: dR,
                                title: dS[a3].$t,
                                summary: dS.summary.$t[bp](),
                                img: dS.media$thumbnail && dS.media$thumbnail.url,
                                author: dS.author[0].name.$t,
                                comment: dS.thr$total && dS.thr$total.$t,
                                label: dS.category
                            },
                            dP = dS.updated.$t,
                            dO = new cN(dP),
                            dN = dO[bY + ak](),
                            dM = ds[dO[bY + bq]()],
                            dL = dO[bY + bo]();
                        dQ.date = dN + " " + dM + ", " + dL, dH.posts[aC](dQ)
                    }
                }
                var dG = U[dv];
                if (typeof dG === bK && 0 < dH.posts[df] && (dx && (dH.posts = c9(dH.posts)[b8](0, dx)), dC[bw] = dG(dH)[bp](), bV(dC, "visually-hidden"), Defer.dom(".lazy-" + dB, 1, "loaded", M), du)) {
                    var dE = U[du];
                    typeof dE === bK && dE()
                }
            }
        }
    };

    function cE(i, h) {
        var n = new cy;
        n[cz](bY, i), n[c8](bT, Y), n[bz](null), n[cO + bk](dn, function () {
            var o = n[aN][aR](/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
            h[bw] = o[1][L](" &#8211; " + c2, "")
        })
    }
    var E = function (i) {
        for (var h = i[dd]("a"), x = 0; x < h[df]; ++x) {
            var t = h[x],
                o = t[ah],
                n = aZ[cg]("span");
            Q(n, "d-block fw-bold pt-2 jt-text-primary"), t[dg](n), cE(o, n)
        }
    };

    function ar() {
        cs && cs[N] || g && g[N] ? bV(dc, "header-animate") : Q(dc, "header-animate")
    }

    function F(i, h) {
        function o(t) {
            i[ae](t[T]) || (h(), n())
        }
        var n = function () {
            aZ[aV + bk](O, o)
        };
        aZ[cO + bk](O, o)
    }
    cs && cs[cO + bk](bd, function () {
        ar(), this[N] && a(function () {
            aZ[C]("search-input")[aD]()
        }, 100), F(ac, function () {
            cs[N] = !1, ar()
        })
    }), g && g[cO + bk](bd, function () {
        ar(), this[N] ? (aT(bm, "show"), F(bm, function () {
            g[N] = !1, ar(), cJ(bm, "show")
        })) : cJ(bm, "show")
    }), di && di[cO + bk](O, function (h) {
        h[cL](), bS(bb, "dark-mode"), b1[bD + a2]("theme", S(bb, "dark-mode") ? "dark" : "light")
    }), U[cO + bk](cu, function () {
        1 <= this[aO] ? Q(dc, "shadow-sm") : bV(dc, "shadow-sm"), 1000 <= this[aO] ? bV(aE, "d-none") : Q(aE, "d-none")
    }, !1), c6 && c6[cO + bk](dn, function () {
        bV(al, "loader")
    });

    function Z(i) {
        if (i != c4[ah] && (Q(al, "loader"), c4[ah] = i, c6[bB] = i), S(al, "d-none")) {
            bV(al, "d-none");
            var h = V[aM][aR](/<script.*?src='(.*?)'/)[1];
            Defer.js(h, "comment-js", 500, function () {
                BLOG_CMT_createIframe(cR + "www.blogger.com/rpc_relay.html")
            })
        }
    }
    cr && cr[cO + bk](O, function (h) {
        h[cL](), Z(this[ah]), "add-comment" != al[a8][cW] && aZ[C]("add-comment")[dg](al)
    });
    for (var cd = 0; cd < bU[df]; ++cd) {
        bU[cd][cO + bk](O, function (i) {
            i[cL]();
            var h = this[bY + bg]("data-comment-id");
            Z(this[ah]), al[a8][cW] != "c" + h && aZ[C]("c" + h)[dg](al)
        })
    }
    if (! function (i, h) {
            U[cO + bk](cu, function () {
                var o, n = this[aO];
                n < h && S(dc, "header-hidden") ? o = a(function () {
                    bV(dc, "header-hidden")
                }, 500) : h < n && S(dc, "header-animate") && (cK(o), Q(dc, "header-hidden")), h = n
            }, !1)
        }(this, 0), 0 < P[df]) {
        for (var cd = 0; cd < P[df]; ++cd) {
            var cG = P[cd],
                cQ = cG[bw],
                cq = 'src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" loading="lazy" lazyload="true" data-src="$1"',
                cS = aZ[cg]("textarea");
            cS[bw] = cQ[L](/src="(.*?)"/g, cq);
            var bv = aZ[cg]("div");
            bv[bw] = cS.value, 0 == cd && Q(bv, "feature-image mb-3"), cG[a8][cX + cm](bv, cG)
        }
        Defer.dom('[lazyload="true"]', 1, "loaded", M, null, {
            rootMargin: "200%"
        })
    }
    if (null !== cU) {
        if (null !== aS && null !== aY && (aY[bw] = aS[bw], aY[bD + bg]("data-no-item", aS[bY + bg]("data-no-item"))), null !== aK) {
            for (var de, cB = cU[dd](ch + "," + cf), co = aK[cV], ax = co[df], J = [], cd = 0; cd < cB[df]; cd++) {
                de = cB[cd][ct](cf), de && cB[cd] != de || J[aC](cB[cd])
            }
            for (var cd = 0; cd < ax; cd++) {
                var b0, b2;
                0 == cd ? b0 = J[0] : (b2 = cd == ax - 1 ? J[df] - 1 : cA[bP](J[df] / ax) * cd, b0 = J[b2][cc]), b0 && b0[a8][cX + cm](co[cd][bO](!0), b0)
            }
            aK[be] = ""
        }
        if (bH && bH != D && av && null !== cU[bX]) {
            for (var K = cU[dd]("h2,h3,h4,h5,h6"), b5 = aZ[cg]("div"), A = cU[bR](r), b7 = [], cd = 0; cd < K[df]; cd++) {
                var ce = K[cd],
                    b4 = ce[cp][L](/[^\w!?]/g, "_")[L](/__/g, "_"),
                    b9 = w(ce[ck][L]("H", ""));
                ce[cW] = b4, b7[aC]({
                    level: b9,
                    title: ce[cp],
                    id: b4
                })
            }
            null === A && (A = cU[bX]), 0 < b7[df] && (b5[bw] = av(b7)[bp](), A && A[a8][cX + cm](b5, A))
        }
    }! function (i, h) {
        bK == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["exports"], h) : dp == typeof exports ? h(i.dragscroll = {}) : h(exports)
    }(this, function (i) {
        var h, o, t = [],
            n = function (x, ds) {
                for (x = 0; x < t[df];) {
                    (ds = (ds = t[x++])[aL] || ds)[aV + bk](a7, ds.md, 0), U[aV + bk](u, ds.mu, 0), U[aV + bk](cj, ds.mm, 0)
                }
                for (t = [][b8][ag](aZ[s]("drag-scroll")), x = 0; x < t[df];) {
                    ! function (dt, dy, dx, dw, dv, du) {
                        (du = dt[aL] || dt)[cO + bk](a7, du.md = function (dz) {
                            dt[bf + bg]("nochilddrag") && aZ[aG](dz[k], dz[j]) != du || (dw = 1, dy = dz[aB], dx = dz[aA], dz[cL]())
                        }, 0), U[cO + bk](u, du.mu = function () {
                            dw = 0
                        }, 0), U[cO + bk](cj, du.mm = function (dz) {
                            dw && ((dv = dt[aJ] || dt)[aW] -= h = -dy + (dy = dz[aB]), dv[cl] -= o = -dx + (dx = dz[aA]), dt == aZ[br] && ((dv = aZ[bN])[aW] -= h, dv[cl] -= o))
                        }, 0)
                    }(t[x++])
                }
            };
        m == aZ[cT] ? n() : U[cO + bk](dn, n, 0), i[I] = n
    });

    function e() {
        dl("j" + bM, ca, 14), dl("j" + a9, !1, 14), bG(W + " " + cX + " " + bF + " " + bM)
    }

    function cI(i) {
        var h = az(i);
        h && h[bM] == c1 && h[aU] == bc ? (dl("j" + a9, !0, 14), dl("j" + bM, ca, 14)) : e()
    }
    var ci = function () {
        4 === this[cT] && (200 === this[dq] ? "" == this[cZ] ? e() : cI(this[aN][bp]()) : e())
    };
    ca && (ca !== cw || dh == dp) ? a(function () {
        var h = new cy;
        h[am] = ci, h[cz](bY, d, !0), h[bz](null)
    }, 8000) : (!ca || dh != bI) && e();
    var bZ = function (dv) {
        var du = dv[bY + bg]("data-url") || "#",
            dt = dv[bY + bg]("data-duration") || 300,
            ds = dv[bY + bg]("data-increase") || 3,
            x = dv[bY + bg]("data-after") || "Get Link",
            t = dv[bR](".progress-bar"),
            o = dv[bR](".btn"),
            n = 0,
            i = bl(function () {
                n += ds, 100 <= n && (n = 100, dr(i), bV(o, "disabled"), o[bw] = x, o[bD + bg]("href", du)), t[bD + bg]("style", "width:" + n + "%")
            }, dt)
    };
    if (bn) {
        for (var bA, cd = 0; cd < ai[df]; ++cd) {
            bA = ai[cd], bA[bw] = bn(bA)[bp]()
        }
    }
    a1 && bW && (U[aD](), U[cO + bk](b3, function () {
        a(function () {
            var i = aZ[ay];
            if ("IFRAME" == i[ck] && i[ct]("." + dm)) {
                var h = c5 + 1;
                h >= cb ? dl("j" + aa, h, bi, "hours") : dl("j" + aa, h, bj, "minutes")
            }
        }, 50)
    })), ao && (aZ[a3] = aZ[a3][L](" \u2013 ", " \u2013 " + cH + " " + ao + " \u2013 ")), Defer.dom(".lazyload", 1, "loaded", M), Defer.dom("#post-pager", 1, null, E, null, {
        rootMargin: "200%"
    }), Defer.dom("#pagination", 1, null, dk, null, {
        rootMargin: "200%"
    }), Defer.dom(".custom-posts", 1, null, jo[da], null, {
        rootMargin: "200%"
    }), Defer.dom(".generate-url", 1, "loaded", bZ);

    function c() {
        if (aZ[aV + bk](cj, c), aZ[aV + bk](aj, c), aZ[aV + bk](cu, c), !dj) {
            if (a1 && (!bW || bW && c5 < cb)) {
                var h = aZ[bR]("ins." + dm);
                null !== h && (adsbygoogle = U[dm] || [])[aC]({
                    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-" + a1,
                    enable_page_level_ads: !0,
                    overlays: {
                        bottom: !0
                    }
                }), Defer.js(cR + "pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/" + dm + ".js", dm, 100)
            }
            B && B != D && Defer.js(cR + "www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=" + B, b6, 100, function () {
                function i() {
                    dataLayer[aC](arguments)
                }
                i("js", new Date), i(X, B)
            }), b && b != D && Defer.js(cR + "www.gstatic.com/" + a6 + "js/" + v + "/" + a6 + "-app.js", a6 + "-app", 100, function () {
                Defer.js(cR + "www.gstatic.com/" + a6 + "js/" + v + "/" + a6 + "-database.js", a6 + "-db", 100, function () {
                    var n = aZ[dd](".jt-get-view");
                    firebase.initializeApp({
                        databaseURL: b
                    });
                    for (var i = firebase.database(), ds = 0; ds < n[df]; ds++) {
                        var x = n[ds],
                            t = x[bY + bg]("data-id"),
                            o = i.ref("pages/" + t);
                        o.once(aM, function (du, dt) {
                            return function (dw) {
                                var dv = dw.exists() ? dw.val() : 0;
                                0 < dv && (du[bw] = dv, bV(du[a8], "d-none")), du[bY + bg]("data-increment") == bI && (du[bD + bg]("data-increment", !1), dv = w(dv) + 1, dt.set(dv))
                            }
                        }(x, o))
                    }
                })
            }), bu && bu()
        }
        R && Defer.js(cR + "cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/" + bQ + "@" + a0 + "/dist/js/" + bQ + ".min.js", bQ, 100, a4)
    }
    aZ[cO + bk](cj, c), aZ[cO + bk](aj, c), aZ[cO + bk](cu, c)
}();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can deobfuscate the code by going to https://www.dcode.fr/javascript-unobfuscator

However I recommend trying to implement the features you want from their site yourself or by using a library, rather than trying to track down and figure out what exactly they're doing.

Comment: This site you provided did not work well for me, in addition, I already mentioned that I am 10% in JavaScript and I want to learn writing code from others and try to understand how it works

Comment: @MintStudy you're fine to do that but working with obfuscated code isn't the way to go about it. Check out repos on Github